# Prompt confirm before Leaving edited html form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

If user tries to leave unsaved edited form, a message box pop-up

"This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.
Leave Page and Stay on Page"

Can we invoke this confirmation box through some special function of browser? I want to implement it in AngularJS application

[image]

Comment: You must be aiming for window.confirm() method.

Comment: possibly duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event

Comment: @EricG that is not a confirm prompt in the screenshot.

Comment: @epascarello, Agreed, but actually it isnt obvious what he means. The "onbeforeunload" function cannot be invoked manually, but can be edited and this becomes clear 'whenever' it shows. The confirm dialog CAN be invoked manually but doesnt know by default whether or not the page was edited. So my answer wasnt that irrelevant compared to "onbeforeonload" I think ;)

Comment: @SubRed - this isn't actually a duplicate question, when it comes to Angular. See my answer.

Comment: @blesh Oh sorry I didn't notice this is for AngularJS application :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Warlock's answer is partly right, but in doing so, you'd break testability.

In Angular, you'd want to use [$window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$window), and you'll want to watch `$dirty` on your form. You'll need to have a named form, notice `name="myForm"` below. Then you can `$watch` `$dirty` on the form in your `$scope`:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var win = $window;
  $scope.$watch('myForm.$dirty', function(value) {
    if(value) {
      win.onbeforeunload = function(){
        return 'Your message here';
      };
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<form name="myForm">
  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
</form>
```

Here's a plunk to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/3NHpU1

Comment: Thanks. But in AngularJS we have lots of partial views, each have form. This event is not being fire don view change. is there any event which get called before view-change.

Comment: Then it doesn't sound like you're using forms in angular properly. if you have `<form name="whatever">` then you should be able to `$scope.$watch('whatever.$dirty)`, you'd have to do that for each form, which is a little bit of a pain, I suppose.

Comment: @StefanLobato Some browsers won't show prompts unless the user interacts with the page first. See notes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 5):

You could use the "onbeforeunload" event. The syntax is as follows:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Your text string you want displayed in the box";
}
```

This event will popup that confirmation dialog that you described above asking whether or not the user truly wants to leave the page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to cancel the route change when you determine your form is dirty, you can do this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This will cancel the routing and keep you on the current page.

Answer (score 4):

I liked @blesh's answer, but I think it fails to account for internal url changes (for example, if you use ngView on your application and visit different internal views). window.onbeforeunload never gets called when the hash # changes. In this case, you have to listen to both window.onbeforeunload and $locationChangeStart:

```
app.controller('OtherCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', function($scope, $window, $location, $rootScope) {
  $scope.message = "This time you get a confirmation.";
  $scope.navigate = function() {
    $location.path("/main");
  }
  var getMessage = function() {
    if($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
      return $scope.message;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  $window.onbeforeunload = getMessage;
  var $offFunction = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(e) {
    var message = getMessage();
    if(message && !confirm($scope.message)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $offFunction();
    }
  });
}]);
```

See plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/R0Riek?p=preview

Comment: I'd have to agree with your assessment. Just listening for onbeforeunload doesn't handle angular route changes, which is a really important component of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily protect your form with jQuery with this simple unobtrusive code. Put in just before your `</body>` closing tag.

```
(function () {
    jQuery('form').one('change', function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            return 'Form protection';
        };
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use `$window.alert` or `$window.confirm` or beforeroutechange

[Angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route)