# AngularJS changing route using $route

Tags: angularjs

I am implementing authentication checking using $routeChangeStart as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541695/angular-js-redirecting-to-a-certain-route-based-on-condition) and looking for a way to preserve all detail provided in the `next` object.  AngularJS [documentation on $route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route) shows that you can set the `$route.current` and I was hoping that I do something like the following to change the `$route` instead of using `$location`:

```
$route.current = { templateUrl: 'detail.html', controller: 'MainCtrl' };
$route.reload();
```

I know that $route.current can be updated because `console.log` after setting it shows that it does pickup the change:

```
console.log("current route: ", $route.current.templateUrl );
```

Unfortunately it does not work.  The application I am creating have additional parameters defined using `$routeProvider` that I would like to preserve.

Any ideas?

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DJ4gG27Hfc0nU5qmQeHa?p=preview) I setup to illustrate this.

Comment: I, of course, could be mistaken, but I don't think you can do this with `$route` (`$route.current` is read-only). If you need to save state across multiple controllers, consider using a service backed by in-memory data, cookies, localStorage, etc.

Comment: maybe $location.absUrl()  will help. Save its value, then you can log in and finally set the location to the stored value

Comment: @BrandonTilley that is the problem, $route.current is not read-only.  If you add a `console.log("current route: ", $route.current.templateUrl );` after setting it, you will see that it has been updated.

Comment: @Anton unfortunately $location does not help as I set additional parameters as part of the route.  For example, I have a parameter called 'auth' and was hoping that I can turn it on and off using code.  There are certainly other way that I can accomplish that but this question is really about what I can do with $route.  The answer might simple as what Brandon said: no, you can't.

Comment: Sorry, by read only, I meant that you are only meant to read it. The value is only there for you to inspect, not change. Being JavaScript in the browser, it's not literally read only.

Comment: @BrandonTilley sorry, I should have been clearer as well.  What I meant is that in the angular.js, all the magic related to $route seems to happen in `updateRoute` where it sets `last = $route.current`.  I was hoping that by setting it, and confirming that it was set, would trigger necessary changes.  An the answer is unfortunately no.  I would have to dive into the detail of `updateRoute` to figure out the true impact.