# is it possible to have multiple views inside multiple views in angular ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to have multiple named views inside another named view like this

```html
<div ui-view="1">
  <div ui-view="a"></div>
  <div ui-view="b"></div>
  <div ui-view="c"></div>
</div>
<div ui-view="2"></div>
<div ui-view="3"></div>
```

If its possible, can I update the ui-view="a" with changes in ui-view="b" ?

Comment: [I believe so](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views)

Comment: Is the problem setting a template against multiple nested views? or passing data between the views?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create your state provider acordingly.
Like "1", "1.a", "1.b", "2", "3" etc

in the template html of your `ui-view="1"` you need to add a view.

Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569581/parts-of-page-as-subviews-in-angular). I think it will solve your problem.

Check [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#nested-states--views) out also.

Comment: if i give 1.a and 1.b, either a or b can only be visible in the view. I want them both active

Comment: Are your looking kind of this? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views