# AngularJS: Trying to understand the technology behind loading new content without reloading a page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

- Using AngularJS 1.5.8 and Django/Django REST Framework as the back-end.
- At this points have two URLs (`app/` for login and `app/dashboard` as the main content); would be great to just have `app/`.
- `login` and `dashboard` I have as components; `navbar` and `sidebar` I have as directives.
- Using [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) currently and somethings I am reading lead me to believe I should be using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to accomplish this.

Just some basic things that came to mind.

My sidebar has several tools I am developing. I want the user to be able to click on them, and then have the content related to that tool load in the main content area without the page refreshing or the URL changing.

Some of what I have read suggests `ui-router` might be better for this purpose? I am not, sure as I am just learning AngularJS and still struggling with its concepts. Thus, I don't have any code to post that needs to be fixed. Primarily just trying to understand the concepts and technology I need to look into to accomplish this. Makes it hard to lookup results on Google and SO when you aren't even sure what the terminology and tech is that you should be looking for.

Not sure if `ngRoute` or `ui-router` should be used; whether the modules should be built as `components` or `directives`; if the content for each tool stays in its own HTML template; etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat broad question but what you are looking for is client-side routing. Both ngRoute and ui-router offer this functionality and in very similar ways except ui-router offers significant extensibility with nested routes and multiple named view containers.

My advice is to start with ngRoute and learn it's ins and outs and then switch to ui-router if you find you need this extra functionality.

Client-side routing can either be used with the hash-bang (#/) or using html5 mode you can use a base URL that would function visually like server-side routing.

Now you've got the terms to search at least so happy Googling!

Comment: Thanks, got what I needed based on this. I did end up just going with `ui-router`. Also, found this question very helpful in finally getting to a point where I accomplish what I was after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569581/parts-of-page-as-subviews-in-angular.