# Angular change location changes path but browser goes to wrong page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like my app to send non-logged in users to a login page.  Based on a popular answer here, the app watches for routeChangeStart, like this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    if ($rootScope.currentUser === null) {
        var allowPublic = ["partials/logIn.html", "partials/start.html"];
        var allowed = _.contains(allowPublic, next.templateUrl);
        if (!allowed) {
            $location.path("/logIn").replace();
        }
    }
});
```

This logic runs correctly, except that changing $location.path doesn't work.  **The address bar in the browser changes to /logIn, but the view still shows the non-permitted partial**.  Does anybody have an idea why?

My routes are setup like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/start', {templateUrl: 'partials/start.html', controller: 'StartController'});
$routeProvider.when('/logIn', {templateUrl: 'partials/logIn.html', controller: 'LogInController'});
$routeProvider.when('/restricted', {templateUrl: 'partials/restricted.html', controller: 'RestrictedController'});
```

The start page controller sometimes tries to navigate to the restricted page, like this:

```
// in StartController
$scope.pressedButton = function() {
    $location.path('/restricted');
    // I'd like to catch this and redirect using the previous logic if user is not logged in
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across this in the future, here's what I did, though I can't say I fully understand why I had to do it.  The fix was to wrap the location change in a timeout.

```
        if (!allowed) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $location.path("/logIn").replace();
            }, 0);
        }
```

It think the problem arose because my code was trying to change the location while it's listening for location changes, leading to a regress (which is then halted by the fact that the second call is for a permitted location).  By wrapping the path change in $timeout, I guess I'm letting the first location change finish before forcing the redirect.

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I came to the conclusion reading the "Triggering Events Programmatically" section [in this angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest).

This is sensible, I guess, but I wonder why the many route security solutions I read about didn't mention this danger.  ([e.g. see the massively up-voted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542936/1272965)).