# How to set my initial page to a Login html page

Tags: angularjs, authentication

In my AngularJS SPA, I would like to force a sort of splash page with a login form. Once the user is authenticated, then I would like to load the full website.

Here is my `app.config`, which currently triggers a modal logon. However, this is not the right solution for my application. I do not want to load any nav bars UNTIL the user is fully logged in.

```js
angular
.module('rage')
.config(config);

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
$stateProvider
 .state('corp', {
  url: "/corp",
  templateUrl: "app/views/corp.html",
  data: { pageTitle: 'RAGE' }
 })
 .state('maint', {
  url: "/maint",
  templateUrl: "app/views/maint.html",
  data: { pageTitle: 'RAGE' }
 })
 .state('main', {
  url: "/dashboard",
  templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard.html",
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  data: { pageTitle: 'RAGE', requireLogin: true },
  resolve: {
   authUser: ['$rootScope', 'loginService', 'userService', function ($rootScope, loginService, userService, authUser) {
    return loginService.loginModal().then(function (user) {
     $rootScope.userID = user.userId;
     initSession(user, $rootScope, loginService, userService);
     return user;
    })
   }]
  }
 })
 .state('login', {
  url: "/login",
  templateUrl: "app/components/login/login.html",
  controller: 'LoginCtrl'            
 })
 
}
function initSession(user, $rootScope, loginService, userService) {

userService.getInitParams().then(function (envJson) {
 $rootScope.rageSessionVars = envJson;
 userService.initRazor(envJson).then(function (data) {
  var response = data.status;
  if (response.match(/SUCCESS/g)) {
   userService.openUserSession(razorEnvJson).then(function (data) {
    // ...
   });
  }
 });
});

}
```

Should I handle this in my `app.config` ?

Any advice is appreciated.

thanks,
Bob

Comment: Please have a look at the answers to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541695/redirecting-to-a-certain-route-based-on-condition). Is there something that's working for you? I think binding to `$stateChangeStart` event in run method could work for you.

Comment: My main issue is that, although I do have a resolve working on my"main" state above, the login modal I use still allows the side and top nav areas to load in the background. I need to halt all loading..thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing.Make a state like below.

```
state("context", {
            url:"/context",
            template: '',
            controller : "contextCtrl"
}).
```

And in **'contextCtrl'** you should check if the user is **authenticated** or not like below

```
app.controller("contextCtrl",function($scope, $rootScope, userLoginService,$state, SessionService){
    if(SessionService.getSessionUser()==null){
            $state.go("login");
    }else{
        if(SessionService.getSessionUser().authorities[0].authority=="ROLE_ADMIN"){
            $state.go("dashboard");
        }
    }
});
```

**SessionService** in above code is your **localStorageService** which stores the logged in user. Now in dashBoardCtrl of dashboard state (MainCtrl in your case) you should check on every request whether the user is authenticated or not. Following service checks the response of every request.If the response's status is 403,page will be redirected to login page.

```
service.factory('APIInterceptor', function($q) {
       return {
         'response': function(response) {
               // do something on error
                 if(response.status == 302 ){
                  window.location.href = contextPath;  
                  return $q.reject(response);
                 }
                 return response;
             },
         'responseError': function (rejection) {
             if(rejection.status === 0) {
              location.reload();
             }
             if(rejection.status == 403 ){
                 window.location.href = contextPath+'/#/login';
                  return $q.reject(response);
             }
             return $q.reject(rejection);
         }
      };
    })
```

With this,if the user is not authenticated he will be redirected to login page.Hope it helps you.

Comment: So I would inject the APIinterceptor svc into my MainCtrl in order to ensure that the user is authenticated upon each http request?  And where is the authUser api method getting called?

Comment: Inject your APIinterceptor in your angular module.There is no need to add it in MainCtrl. It will work automatically.It just checks the response of every request,if its 403 redirection occurs.

Comment: would you have time to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109250/angular-ng-submit-not-firing-the-desired-controller-method ?

Comment: how do I inject the $location and/or $state provider into `APIInterceptor`. In see you're using `location` from the native browser.

Comment: Replace service.factory('APIInterceptor', function($q) {

with

service.factory('APIInterceptor',function($q, $location,$state){