# Angular ng-submit not firing the desired controller method

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

In Angular 1.4.7, I'm trying to implement a basic login form in this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/xQEN1ZNN5ZEw1CSwNw97?p=preview (Please click on the red `Log into Dashboard` button on the Home route).

However for some reason I cannot get the `login()` method to fire in my `loginCtrl` controller code.

Instead what it's doing is an old-school URL redirect with the user/password parameters passed in as form variables. I can't figure out what's wrong.

**Key points here in my posted code:**

1) login-form.html contains `ng-submit="login.loginUser()"`

2) app.config contains the login route `'login'` which hooks into `'LoginCtrl as login'`

3) `'LoginCtrl'` contains anonymous method `login.loginUser`

4) app.js redirects to my `login` state if userId is undefined.

Here's the `login-form.html` template :

```html
<div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
<form name="form" ng-submit="login.loginUser()" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="login.username" required />
        <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="login.password" required />
        <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
        <img ng-if="login.dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my Login Controller code :

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('rage').controller('LoginCtrl',
        ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$cookies', '$modalInstance', '$q', 'datacontext', 'loginService', 'userService', authenticate]);

    function authenticate($rootScope, $scope, $cookies, $modalInstance, $q, datacontext, loginService, userService) {

        var login = this;

        login.loginUser = function () {
            login.dataLoading = true;
            loginService.authUser(login.user, login.password);
        };

    }
})();
```

Here's the app.config with routes:

```js
angular
.module('rage')
.config(config);

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard.html",
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    data: { pageTitle: 'RAGE', requireLogin: true }
})
.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "app/components/login/login-form.html",
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    controllerAs: 'login'
})

}
```

and my app.js

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('rage', [
       'ui.router',
       'ui.bootstrap',
       'ui.dashboard',
       'kendo.directives',
       'ngCookies'     
    ]).run(['$rootScope', '$state',  '$location', 'userService', 'loginService', init]);

    function init($rootScope, $state, $location, userService, loginService) {
        $rootScope.rageSessionVars = {};
        $rootScope.$state = $state;

        
        if ($rootScope.rageSessionVars.userID == undefined) {
            $state.go('login');
        }
              
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are not creating any module. You are writing `angular.module('rage')` instead you should write `angular.module('rage', [])` in your app.config file.

From the doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

To create a new module:

```
// Create a new module
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
```

Then define your module as `ng-app="rage"` in your HTML's body or `<html>` tag.

Since, you are not creating any module at all and not enabling the Angular in your HTML, your form is getting submitted like old-school form submission.

So modify your app config as:

```
var myModule = angular.module('rage', [])
    .config(config) // ... your code
```

And, your controller code is fine but you can also use it like:

```
myModule.controller('LoginCtrl', function() {}) // ....
```

Comment: my mistake not adding the app.js code. I updated my post to show app.js

Comment: What about `ng-app="rage"` in your HTML view? Have you added it

Comment: yes I certainly did. My full application works, but now I'm trying to retrofit a new login process.

Comment: If you are using chrome browser, there is an option to `Preserve Log` (might be with a different name in other browser), please check that option and then submit your form to see if there is any javascript error while you submit

Comment: I'm getting a modalInstanceProvider error, but I have been getting that for a while now. That error was there before this new login process.

Comment: Can you please get rid of that error once? Angular might be failing to prevent the event of form submission. Just remove the `$modalInstance` dependency from the controller and then try again.

Comment: Also, how are you defining your controller in ng-controller

Comment: plz see the `app.config` routes above where my `controllerAs` is defined. Also see this plunk I've take and modified to try and simulate. Run the plunk then click on DASHBOARD to see the login redirect - http://plnkr.co/edit/xQEN1ZNN5ZEw1CSwNw97?p=preview

Comment: So, if you click on the red DASHBOARD button it will redirect to the login-form page, but never hits the login-controller.js method called `login.loginUser`

Comment: So did you get the fix and got your code running?

Comment: yes, but a different problem. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111224/angularjs-login-form-with-ng-click-not-working/33112368#33112368