# AngularJS Login form with ng-click not working

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

I wrote a basic login form in this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/xQEN1ZNN5ZEw1CSwNw97?p=preview (click on the red Log into Dashboard button on the Home route).

However for some reason I cannot get the login() method to fire in my loginCtrl controller code.

Why is this example working, and mine is not ? http://plnkr.co/edit/H4SVl6?p=preview

Instead what it's doing is an old-school URL redirect with the user/password parameters passed in as form variables. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is `LoginCtrl` code as well as the `login-form.html` template :

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('routerApp').controller('LoginCtrl',
        ['$rootScope', '$scope', authenticate]);

    function authenticate($rootScope, $scope,   userService) {

        var login = this;

        login.loginUser = function () {
            login.dataLoading = true;
            //loginService.authUser(login.user, login.password);  // TO DO !!!
        };
        login.test = function () {
            var test = true;
        };
    }
})();
```

```html
<div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
<form  ng-submit="login.loginUser()" name="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="login.username" required />
        <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="login.password" required />
        <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
        <img ng-if="login.dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my local app, it is posting the old-style form variables via the URL, and I cannot get it to fire the `login.loginUser` function below inside `LoginCtrl`.

thnk you in advance...

Bob

Comment: Do you have any errors in the JS console?

Comment: @ThinkingMedia - no errors. If you're familiar with Chrome tools, you can hit F12 to bring up tools and then use the Sources tab to drill down into the login-controller.js file for debugging... scroll down to `run.plnkr.co` in the `Sources` listing. thanks.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia - this separate online version is working, but I can't figure out why mine is not. http://plnkr.co/edit/H4SVl6?p=preview

Comment: @bob I can't fine in your plunkr where do you have defined `userService`. Can you let me know whick file it should be.

Comment: @DianaR - I have removed `userService` from my plunk. It's in my local project but I inadvertently left it in the plunk. It's not needed for this sample. Anyhow, it still won't fire.

Comment: The plunk still doesn't work. Even if I try ` ng-submit="loginUser()"` without the `controller as ` syntax, and also change it to `$scope.loginUser` in `LoginCtrl` - it still won't fire.

Comment: The login controller declaration is a bit odd, I've changed a little bit and also changed the login template and got it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for some odd reason (perhaps ui-router versioning) the `controllerAs` is not working.

Diana´s answer is valid, but it doesn´t use the `controlleras` syntax.
If you still want to use it, change the `ui-router` setting to:

```
.state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "login-form.html",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl as login',
    })
```

That should do the trick ;)

Check it out:
http://plnkr.co/edit/OCqNexVeFFxt4kUuEVc1?p=preview

Comment: that worked ! funny thing is I tried that, but sometimes you get so deep that you just get buried in confusion.

Comment: I always prefix my controller names with `$` to prevent collision with scope variables. It also makes it easier to spot controllers in the templates. Never had an issue with controllerAs. I suspect login was getting overwritten in the scope, and since expressions don't throw errors it was silently failing.

Answer (score 2):

The controller change I applied is:

```
angular.module('routerApp').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope) {

    $scope.loginUser = function () {
        $scope.dataLoading = true;
        //loginService.authUser(login.user, login.password);  // TO DO !!!
    };
    $scope.test = function () {
        var test = true;
    };
})
```

and in the template I removed `login.` from the ng-if and ng-submit.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0YQZIr94Sgqp8iU8VZYG?p=preview) is a working plunks.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't like my `controllerAs: 'login'` syntax in `app.js`. Something to do with Angular's `ng-submit` perhaps ?

Comment: Hello @diana-r, please note that this controller declaration does not work well with minification ;)

Comment: @Fedaykin at least bob got a working example and can start dig from there. if he needs a min of his controller adding in front of `function` the `['$scope'...` is a quick change, my goal was to get it working

Comment: @DianaR - i'm sorry but it was the `as` syntax that I was looking for. Your time greatly appreciated.