# How to display logon page and get user name and password from Angular?

Tags: angularjs, authentication

In my angular controller, I have the following code to check if logon is required:

```
$scope.checkApi = "api/check";
$http.post($scope.checkApi).then(function (response) 
{
    if (response.status != 200) 
    {
        alert("Logon required.");
    }
}, function (response) 
{
    if (response.status != 200)
    {
        alert("Logon required.");
    }
});
```

If logon is required, then from the controller I want to display the logon page to get user name and password, then use the user name and password to access the web API like this:

```
var userCredential = btoa(userName + ":" + password");
$http.get(usersApi, { headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + userCredential } }).then(function (response) 
{
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541695/redirecting-to-a-certain-route-based-on-condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to login page instead to giving alert. Use $window.location.href=  url mapping for login page;

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I added the following line:

$window.location.href = 'pages/logon.html';

The logon page will display, then how can I get the user name and password from the logon page and go back to my main application?

Comment: Ideally, the logon page should be opened as a model dialog on top of the main page, the main page should always stays.

In my other case, I have a dialog like this in one of my html file:

<div id="adModal" role="dialog" class="modal fade modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="modal-footer">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

This dialog can be opened by button like this:
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adModal">

Is possible to open this dialog from AngularJS instead of by clicking a button?