# Conditional expression in $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, session, authentication, angular-routing

*I have an application with a **working** system of authentication. My issue here is that when a user is connected, he can still access by URL to the login page. I would like to redirect all connected users to home page instead of login page.*

So, when someone ask for `/authentication/login`:

- If the user is connected, he will be redirected to `/home`.
- If nobody is connected, access to `authentication/login` is open.

---

Here is my actual working code (it **doesn't** redirect a connected user to the home page).

```
angular.module('authentication').config(RouteConfig);
RouteConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider', 'UserSession'];

function RouteConfig($routeProvider, UserSession) {
    $routeProvider.when('/authentication/login/', {
        templateUrl: 'section/authentication/login.tmpl',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'lo'
    });
}
```

---

Is that possible to add a **conditional statement** in the above code?
Something like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/authentication/login/', {
    if(UserSession.getUser() != null) {
        // Go to Home page instead
    } else {
        // Normal way
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can understand the following code as:

> On every route change, "if a connected user wants to access
>   `/authentication/login/`, then he will be redirect to `/home`".

```
angular.module('authentication').run(function($rootScope, $location, Session) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
        if(Session.getUser() != null && next.$$route.originalPath == '/authentication/login/') {
            $location.path("/home");
        }
    });
});
```

---

*This solution is inspired of [@st.never's answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542936/4927984).*

Answer (score 3):

You can use this.

```
  $routeProvider.when('$routeProvider.',
    {
      redirectTo: function (routeParams, path, search) {
        console.log(routeParams);
        console.log(path);
        console.log(search);
        return "/";
      }
    })
```

Try to return the home route conditionally in return statement.
For more information please refer to redirectTo in the [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) docs  or look here at [Thinkster](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/redirect-to)

Comment: I don't understand what is the expect result, can you explain a bit more your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional statement like this.

```
angular.module('authentication').config(RouteConfig);
RouteConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider', 'UserSession'];

function RouteConfig($routeProvider, UserSession) {
 $routeProvider.when('/authentication/login/', {
    templateUrl: 'section/authentication/login.tmpl',
    controller: 'LoginController',
    controllerAs: 'lo',
    resolve: {
      factory: checkRouting
    }
 });
}


var checkRouting= function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {
  if ($rootScope.userProfile) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post("/yourUrl",data)
        .success(function (response) {
            $location.path("/login");
            deferred.resolve(true);
        })
        .error(function () {
            deferred.reject();
            $location.path("/home");
         });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks, but provide [**your source**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541695/redirecting-to-a-certain-route-based-on-condition), next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar method in one of my Angular applications. In the route's config you can add any key you like and access these keys using the `$routeParams` service.

So for your example:

```
function RouteConfig($routeProvider, UserSession) {
    $routeProvider.when('/authentication/login/', {
        templateUrl: 'section/authentication/login.tmpl',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'lo',
        blockAuthenticated: true // <-- add a new flag, something like this 
    });
}
```

Then somewhere else in your application that is most appropriate, e.g. `module.run()`

```
function run($location, $routeParams, UserSession)
{
    // redirect the user home if they're logged in and the route doesn't allow
    // authed users

    if ($routeParams.blockAuthenticated && UserSession.getUser() != null) {
        $location.path('/home');
    }
}
```